# window on scroll end event not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am dynamic appending data to div  using ajax when window scroll end and for that i have used scroll event as below.

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
     if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        alert("scroll");
     }
 });
```

above code is working fine in all browser but not working in IE 8.
for IE8 it through scroll event but will not entered in if condition some how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this condition in scroll event  like this :

```
var down = $(window).height() + 300;
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - down){
```

and now it is resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
 $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 5000, function() {
             //callback function here
 });
```